# Problem to deserialize json to java object of generic type with jackson 2.13.4.2

Tags: jackson, json-deserialization

There's a message defined as below, note **there're different implementations** of the generic type M

```
// The message definition
@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Jacksonized
public class MyMessage<M> {
    @Builder.Default
    Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();

    M content;
}

// One implementation of the generic type M in MyMessage
class ContentType1 {
    String name;
    SomeSimplePojo pojo;
    Map<String, String> contentProps;
}
```

Here's an example of above message:

```
{
    "props": {
        "trace-id": "3468f6022b749dbc"
    },
    "content": {
        "name": "contentExample1",
        "pojo": {
            "field1": "val1",
            "field2": "val2"
        },
        "contentProps": {
            "/Count": "9",
            "/Email": "someone@stackoverflow.com"
        }
    }
}
```

The message was deserialized basically with below code snippet, by com.fasterxml.jackson.* version **2.10.4**. It worked fine before.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyMessage<String> rawMsg = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<MyMessage<String>>() {});

// Here clazzOfM is the class of type M
MyMessage<M> convertedMsg = MyMessage.<M>builder().content(objectMapper.convertValue(rawMsg.getContent(), clazzOfM)).props(rawMsg.getProps()).build();
```

But recently, I upgraded com.fasterxml.jackson.databind to 2.13.4.2, all other com.fasterxml.jackson.* to 2.13.4. Then it failed at this line `MyMessage<String> rawMsg = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<MyMessage<String>>() {});` with Exception, which points to the generic type **M**, field **content** at column 52:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: (String)"{"props":{"trace-id":"3468f6022b749dbc"},"content":{"name":"contentExample1","pojo":{"field1":"val1","field2":"val2"},"contentProps":{"/Count":"9","/Email":"someone@stackoverflow.com"}}}"; line: 1, column: 52] (through reference chain: com.demo.example.MyMessage$MyMessageBuilder["content"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1741)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1515)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1420)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.extractScalarFromObject(DeserializationContext.java:932)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:62)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeSetAndReturn(MethodProperty.java:158)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BuilderBasedDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BuilderBasedDeserializer.java:293)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BuilderBasedDeserializer.deserialize(BuilderBasedDeserializer.java:217)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3612)
```

I tried to change the problematic line to `MyMessage<M> rawMsg = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<MyMessage<M>>() {});`, no exception then, but I still have two questions.

1. Is the above change a correct approach to deserialize json text to MyMessage by jackson 2.13.4(.2)? What is the best practice to this kind of deserialization if the above isn't.
2. After the above change, I notice that the type of **rawMsg.content** is **LinkedHashMap**, it isn't **M(CotentType1 in this test)** as I expected. But the type of **convertedMsg.content** IS **ContentType1** after executing this converting line `MyMessage<M> convertedMsg = MyMessage.<M>builder().content(objectMapper.convertValue(rawMsg.getContent(), clazzOfM)).props(rawMsg.getProps()).build();`.
   I can't understand why the type of **rawMsg.content** is **LinkedHashMap** instead of **ContentType1**. Could someone help explain?

Comment: what is the slash before `Count ` and `Email `?

Comment: I think the slash is nothing specific, it's a normal character of a field name.

Comment: Maybe you can try to delete that slash and try again, I have the impression that slashes are special characters

Comment: I gave that a try, got the same result